Why Dilithium has options starting from security level 2 and not 1?
I am a newbie to PQC, so forgive my gaps in understanding. Most of the NIST PQC standardization selections have 3 levels of security 1, 3 and 5. It is not the case for Dilithium. IS there any specific reason why that is the case?

My guess: it's because the smallest Dilithium paramaeter set is based on a $4 \times 4$ array (of $256 \times 256$ submatrices); it may be that smaller arrays $(3 \times 4, 4 \times 3, 3 \times 5, 5 \times 3)$ don't give level 1 security, and so $4 \times 4$ is the smallest that meets NIST's minimal criteria (and since it also meets level 2, there's no reason not to claim that)

Note that security level 1 is at $2^{143}$ classical gates to attack AES-128 while level 2 is $2^{146}$ classical gates to attack SHA3-256. The difference in classical gates (this is a PQC algorithm after all) is only a factor of $2^3$, i.e. $8$. Or: if the construction of the algorithm has a higher security than the SHA3-256 used internally then you could simply claim that level IMHO. See the table in 4.A.5 Security Strength Categories.
